# How to clear the Google Chrome address bar?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I need to clear the Google Chrome address bar when I load my extension page in the tab.

**[THIS](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/searchtab/ehakebjpbbcppbapabbkomdinmnjppjh)** is my extension, and the address that needs to be cleared looks like this:

```
chrome-extension://<extension-id>/page.html
```

Comment: I do believe you can't do that.

Comment: @Xan I've seen few extensions doing this, but still I don't understand how they can remove the address in the bar (I also thought it was impossible). For example take a look at [this one](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/creativestart/pjoiffklcbocdbniijpdcdffefijfblp). I installed it yesterday, took a look into the code, but I cannot still understand... maybe I should ask a question, but there's already this one.

Comment: Maybe it's because I'm using Canary and in the last update the chrome url overrides behave like this... I don't know.

Comment: @marco I suspect it's because it's registered as a New Tab. It's an exception and nothing in the code does it specifically, it's in the manifest. I do believe you can't do that for an arbitrary extension page. Feel free to write an answer based on that.

Comment: @Xan I'm making some tests to see if the "chrome_urls_overrides" field behaves like so... because I've seen it in the OP's extension. Thanks for the suggestion, I also believe that too.

Comment: @Xan that's so: chrome url overrides leave the default address. The OP was simply creating a new tab.

Comment: @Nesiehr Please edit your question and show all relevant details in the question. When I look at your linked extension, I see that it already uses chrome_url_overrides, which makes me wonder what else you're looking for.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

<sup>* Real solution of your question at the bottom.</sup>

### Clearing browser address bar

This is a pretty old question that came in the mind of almost everyone who ever used JavaScript: *can I replace the whole URL shown in the address bar via JavaScript?* Well, I'm sorry, but the answer is a huge **NOPE**!

**Why can't you clear/replace the URL in the address bar?**

First of all, **JavaScript doesn't actually provide any feature for doing it**, and neither do the most famous browsers (Chrome, Mozilla, Opera...) with their APIs. Secondly, but not less important, **it would be a huge security flaw**. Imagine that some malicious individual wants to steal you some passwords (for example, the Facebook one): if changing the browser's address bar was possible, he would easily create a fake log-in page, copying the original one, and then replace the URL with *"facebook.com/login"* to make it look like you really are on Facebook (it would be pretty easy, huh?). You can obviously see that this could apply to any site and many other services.

### JavaScript `location` and `history`

In JavaScript, there are two common objects used to manipulate the page address:

- The first one is **[`window.location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location)**, which provides you useful information about the current page's location, (such as `.hostname`, `.path`, `.href`, etc), and functions to reload the page or navigate to a different URL. By the way, when changing the address using this object, the page will **always** be reloaded.

  ```
  location.href = "http://newsite.com"; // will reolad
  location.path = "/home.html";         // will reload
  location.replace("google.com");       // will also reload
  ```
- The second, more tricky one, is **[`window.history`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History)**, which also allows you to manipulate the URL without reloading the page, within some limitations (obviously). With its methods `.pushState()` and `.replaceState()` makes you able to change the current **path** without reloading the page. By the way, **you only can navigate through your own site's pages (you cannot change the hostname)**.

  ```
  history.back();
  // will make your browser go back to the previous page

  history.pushState(null, null, "newPage.html");
  // will replace the current path with /newPage.html and add it to the history
  // http://example.com/page1.html -> becomes -> http://example.com/newPage.html
  // now, if you call history.back() the path will be set back to /page1.html  

  history.replaceState(null, null, "newPage.html");
  // will replace the current path with /newPage.html, PLUS it will also replace the current history path
  // http://example.com/page1.html -> becomes -> http://example.com/newPage.html
  // calling history.back() will not set the path back to /page1.html, but to the previous one (if exists)
  ```

  This API is pretty useful. YouTube, Twitter and many other famous sites use this feature to change the URL without reloading the page. This practice **allows you to change part of the page content, without having to reload those parts that stay unchanged** (for example: on Youtube it will only load the new video, info, and related, not the full page).

### Chrome extensions: URL overrides

Google chrome offers to its extensions the possibility to override three common default pages using [the `"chrome_url_overrides"` field](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/override) in your `manifest.json`:

- The New Tab page (`chrome://newtab`) displayed when a new tab is opened.
- The History page (`chrome://history`) containing the navigation history and used to manage it.
- The Bookmarks page (`chrome://bookmarks`) containing all of your bookmarks and used to manage them.

**These are the only three cases which allow you to "replace" the address bar URL in Chrome**. Don't misunderstand what I'm saying: Chrome still doesn't let you change the URL if you are in one of these pages, but it automatically changes it. Using this technique, users can enjoy their beautiful extensions on new tabs, history and bookmarks pages, without seeing the ugly *"chrome-extension://..."* URL.

- Using the `"history"` override will load your custom page instead of the default history one, but will maintain the default `chrome://history` URL.
- Using the `"bookmarks"` override will load your custom page instead of the default bookmarks one, but will also maintain the default `chrome://bookmarks` URL.
- Using the `"newtab"` override will load your custom page instead of the new tab one, but will maintain the default (blank) URL.

**What if I want to navigate to another page maintaining the default address?**

Assuming that you're in one of those three pages and you loaded your custom page instead of the original one, you can use an `<iframe>` set to full width and height to navigate to other pages via JavaScript, changing its `src` attribute:

- HTML:

  ```
  <iframe id="my-frame" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0", frameborder="0"></iframe>
  ```
- JavaScript:

  ```
  var frame = document.getElementById('my-frame');

  frame.src = "/path/to/page.html"; 
  // navigate to a local page stored in your extension

  // or:

  frame.src = "http://www.somesite.com";
  // navigate to an external site (not always possible)
  ```

**NOTE:** navigating to an external site may not be always allowed because of the security policy of that site. If the external page you're trying to load has the `X-Frame-Options` header set to `"SAMEORIGIN"` (like *google.com* for example), you will not be able to load it, and an error will occur:

```
"Refused to display 'http://www.somesite.com/...' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'."
```

### To answer your question:

After all this long tour, there's a simple problem in your extension: you are using `"chrome_url_overrides"` to override the New Tab page with `dashboard.html`, which will execute the script `redirect.js` creating a new tab with `url: "/searchTab.html"`. That's why you see the *"chrome-extension://..."* URL. So **why are you doing all this stuff?** You load a perfectly useless blank page which has the sole purpose of opening a new tab with the `searchTab.html` page... **you don't really need this.** Just delete that useless `/dashboard.html` page and change the overriding page in your `manifest.json` to `/searchTab.html`:

```
...
"chrome_url_overrides": {
    "newtab": "/searchTab.html"
},
...
```

Comment: Also: the New Tab page can contain an `<iframe>` to load any other resource while keeping the address blank.

Comment: @Xan oh yeah that's true, those tricky hacks... although you cannot load sites with header `X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN`.

Comment: Okay, "any other extension page and some external pages"

Comment: @Xan added to the answer, it may be useful to know.

Comment: @Marco Bonelli The reason that I am doing that is because it allows me to autofocus the search bar that my extension uses, in the new tab page the address bar gets the focus no matter what. So I'd prefer to have the autofocus on my extension's input bar instead of the address bar, but the only way to do that is through a page that isn't designated as a new tab page. What you see with the over ride is me experimenting with how to display no part of the address, it didn't work and in the next update will be removed.

Comment: So basically I want to make the new tab page with an ability to autfocus the input bar and don't want to have the ugly address. However I'm starting to believe that can't be accomplished :(

Comment: @Nesiehr oh I see... unfortunately I think that focusing on your own search bar is impossible since that Chrome manages to focus on the address bar in the New Tabs.

Comment: @marco Bonelli Exactly, that is why I have the redirect to the other page, unfortunately it gives the page address.